# Clarification of semantic entailment for the following propositional statement

Tags: logic

I know that *semantic entailment* says that:

$\phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_n \models \psi$

and that we need to show for all valuations in which the propositions in the left hand side evaluate to $T$, $\psi$ evaluates to $T$ as well.

Now my question is what about if the left hand side evaluates to $F$ but $\psi$ evaluates to T does that formula hold a semantic entailment as well ?

For example, the statement:

$q \models p \rightarrow q$

every time q is true $p \rightarrow q$ is true, but there is once instance when $q$ is false and $p$ is false which $p \rightarrow q$ evaluates to true, so would $q$ semantically entails $p \rightarrow q$ ?

Comment: Correct; the def says : every time the permises are true, the conclusion must be true. When $q$ is true, $p \to q$ is true also, irrespective of the truth value of $p$. Thus : $q \vDash p \to q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time q is true $p \rightarrow q$ is true, but there is once instance when $q$ is false and $p$ is false which $p \rightarrow q$ evaluates to true, so would $q$ semantically entails $p \rightarrow q$ ?

The requirement for semantic entailment is exactly that the conclusion must be true *for every* interpretation where *all* the premises *are true*.

This requirement is *not* concerned about what may happen in interpretations where *any* of the premises are *false*.

So the answer is "Yes, $q$ semantically entails $p\to q$, because in *all* valuations where $q$ is valued as true, there $p\to q$ is valued as true too."